# Krypton Controls anyone?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I found the ad on this site to Krypton controls ([and here's another one!](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton)) and was wondering if any of you using vs.net 05 or 08 are using them and how that's working out. If you're answering, please specify which parts you're using (free, ribbons, tabs) and which vs.net you're on, which language(s) you use, along with pros and cons. I know there are probably better suites out there that you may be fond of, but this question is specifically about Krypton controls. We'd be using it with vb.net, .net 3.5, 08, so I'm particularly interested in hearing about your experience in those areas. (I've watched all the screencasts)

Comment: I took a look at the site, and was really surprised that they provided no information about their product. Why would I download something if I can't even tell what it does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been using the **Krypton Controls ToolKit for over 3 years** with **Visual Studio 2005 and 2008** in **.NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 3.5 SP1**.  I have **only used the free ToolKit** and not the Ribbon or Tab controls.  I have used it **only in C**#.

**Pros:**

1. Free
2. Easy to Use - It adds all of the components to the Toolbox so it's very easy to implement.
3. The font rendering is awesome compared to the default windows form controls.
4. The "chrome" which allows you to totally override the look of the application is very nice.
5. The ability to define a master scheme makes it easy to change the look of similar controls in one central location.
6. The support, even on the free Toolkit is awesome, by submitting questions on the Component Factory forum.
7. It includes additional controls that should've been part of the windows form controls including headergroups.

**Cons:**

1. That the other components aren't free ;)
2. In older versions, some controls didn't exist in the ToolKit so you had to use the winform control which wouldn't entirely fit with the application look.  The latest version, however, has most, if not all the controls implemented as Krypton controls.

Here's a quick sample of our options dialog for the "[MuvEnum Address Bar](http://www.muvenum.com/products/freeware/)" using the Krypton Chrome.  It was super easy to create.  Notice the smoothness of the fonts.

[image]

I can't recommend the Krypton Controls enough.

John Rennemeyer

[MuvEnum](http://www.muvenum.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I have been using the free controls in various small internal projects for work for several years. I started following his blog just as he started as MicroISV, from a mention on a MicroISV blog. So I have been through many improvments he has made. The controls he makes are rock solid (at least in my usage of them) and he really listens to what his users want in features and other controls.

I HIGHLY recommend the controls!

Answer (score 3):

I have been using the full suite for the last year and a half.  I have been very happy with the results.  They are easy to use and I haven't run into any issues that I couldn't fix myself (I purchased the source code version).

Definitely recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it. It's quite okay.